# LNK 1120: Unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
class mob;

class player
{
public:
    sf::RectangleShape rect;
    float bottom, left, right, top;
    player(sf::Vector2f position, sf::Vector2f size, sf::Color color);
    void update();
    void collision(mob M);
};
```

Collision definition:

```
void player::collision(mob M)
{
    if(right < M.left)
        rect.setPosition(M.left, rect.getPosition().y);
}
```

I had made the collision function a bool in previous builds so that it would return true or false. Well, after testing it as a bool, I decided to make it a void. However, as soon as I made it a void, I get this error:

> 1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: bool
>   __thiscall player::collision(class mob)" (?collision@player@@QAE_NVmob@@@Z)
>
> 1>C:\SFML_Project\Release\SFML_Project.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1
>   unresolved externals

Also, if necessary, you can find the declaration here:

```
int main()
{

    sf::RenderWindow Window;
    Window.create(sf::VideoMode(800,600),"SFML Project");

    player Cplayer(sf::Vector2f(10,10), sf::Vector2f(32,32), sf::Color::Red);

    mob Cmob(sf::Vector2f(368,284), sf::Vector2f(64,32), sf::Color::Blue);

    Window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(true);

    while(Window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event Event;
        while(Window.pollEvent(Event))
        {
            switch(Event.type)
            {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                Window.close();
                break;
            /*case sf::Event::LostFocus:
                std::cout << "Window lost focus!" << std::endl;
                break;*/
            }
        }

            if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up))
            {
                Cplayer.rect.move(0, -0.2);
            }
            else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down))
            {
                Cplayer.rect.move(0, 0.2);
            }
            else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
            {
                Cplayer.rect.move(0.2, 0);
            }
            else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left))
            {
                Cplayer.rect.move(-0.2, 0);
            }

        Cplayer.update();
        Cmob.update();

        Cplayer.collision(Cmob);


        Window.draw(Cplayer.rect);
        Window.draw(Cmob.rect);
        Window.display();
        Window.clear();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

It seems my post has been marked as a duplicate. This is a not so subtle way of shifting the burden of proof. The answers in the linked thread have nothing to do with my problem and the context drastically changes here.

Comment: @0x499602d2 [So we're still using it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265806/should-regular-faq-style-answers-be-closed-as-too-broad) ;-) ...

Comment: The burden of proof is actually always on the OP to ask quality questions, and the community will close / mark as duplicate questions that don't meet site standards.  While I'm willing to believe you, your edit simply *claims* the questions aren't related, without providing any actual distinction or clarification.  I'll happily vote to re-open if you can help me understand why they're different.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, `main.obj` was built against the older `player` header file and so it still references the version of the method that returns void.  The linker does not find this symbol since the `player.obj` file no longer contains it.

Remove all of your `.obj` files (the "clean" command in your IDE should do this) and rebuild to make sure that it uses the information in the updated header file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sadly, neither cleaning or rebuilding the project worked for me. I probably should have mentioned in the OP that I tried this.

Comment: @RunnyBabbit Then delete the build output directory by hand.  The error clearly shows that it is looking for the `void` method.  If you changed it to `bool` in the implementation file **and** in the header file then you would not get this build error as long as you were building from scratch.